# Java generic class extending comparable cannot be cast to java.base/[Ljava.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am trying to get Object[] array casted to generic sorted
I've implemented this part of the code

```
public class SortedArraySet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Set<T>, Comparator<T> {

    T[] arr;
    int size = 5, index = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    SortedArraySet() {
        arr = (T[]) new Object[5];
        System.out.println("New set was initiated");
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T a, T b) {

        if (a.compareTo(b) > 0)
            return 1;
        else

            return 0;
    }
```

When ever I run it I get the following compilation error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   java.base/[Ljava.lang.Comparable;     at
>   q3.SortedArraySet.(SortedArraySet.java:12)  at
>   q3.q3main.main(q3main.java:6)

At line 6 it is stated as follows

```
SortedArraySet<Integer> sa = new SortedArraySet<Integer>();
```

The code was used to work fine before I added extends Comparable (and so compareTo) in order to sort the set

And is it possible to use Collections.sort?? I have tried but it doesn't seem to work with an array like that!

Comment: Side-note: you do know about `TreeSet`s, right?

Comment: This is 100% runtime.  The compiler put its trust in you when you declared those casts.

Comment: Yes I am aware about every other data structure but I am allowed to use array only :| , I would have solved that in 10 minutes with LinkedList , the point here is to implement a generic array sorted set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use :

```
arr = (T[]) new Comparable[5];
```

Instead of

```
arr = (T[]) new Object[5];
```

As after Type erasing `T[] arr` will be `Comparable[] arr`.So

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[5];
```

Will become

```
Comparable[] arr = (Comparable[]) new Object[5];
```

And obviously, it will throw `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Comment: And can you explain why I have to use comparable as far is it is also extending Object

Comment: @Athl1n3 If it solves your current issue. Then you should accept it and post a new question as too much editing may mislead the question and answer. My suggestion will be posting a new question with the new problem. I would like to help you.

Comment: @Athl1n3 as you can't write a code like `Comparable[] arr = (Comparable[]) new Object[5];` . It will gives you the same excpetion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that and I have solved the previous mentioned issue